# Table doesn't center in website or in dreamweaver

Tags: html

This is my issue, I'm working on a site that I just imported from Photoshop, sliced it up etc. Now I need to center the whole site as a table, but when I set the table width to 100% it doesn't work at all.

Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>Design</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>
<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">
<!-- Save for Web Slices (Design.psd) -->
<table id="Table_01" width="100%" height="1501" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">
            <img src="images/Design_01.gif" width="689" height="210" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/Design_02.gif" width="173" height="210" alt=""></td>
        <td colspan="2">
            <img src="images/Design_03.gif" width="135" height="210" alt=""></td>
        <td colspan="2">
            <img src="images/Design_04.gif" width="209" height="210" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/Design_05.gif" width="1" height="210" alt=""></td>
        <td colspan="6">
            <img src="images/Design_06.gif" width="229" height="210" alt=""></td>
        <td colspan="2">
            <img src="images/Design_07.gif" width="192" height="210" alt=""></td>
        <td colspan="4">
            <img src="images/Design_08.gif" width="214" height="210" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="1" height="210" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="21">
            <img src="images/Design_09.gif" width="1842" height="2" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="1" height="2" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="21">
            <img src="images/Design_10.gif" width="1842" height="161" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="1" height="161" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">
            <img src="images/Design_11.gif" width="48" height="245" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/Design_12.gif" width="74" height="80" alt=""></td>
        <td colspan="17" rowspan="2">
            <img src="images/Design_13.gif" width="1598" height="245" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/Design_14.gif" width="74" height="80" alt=""></td>
        <td rowspan="2">
            <img src="images/Design_15.gif" width="48" height="245" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="1" height="80" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="images/Design_16.gif" width="74" height="165" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/Design_17.gif" width="74" height="165" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="1" height="165" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="21">
            <img src="images/Design_18.gif" width="1842" height="2" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="1" height="2" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="21">
            <img src="images/Design_19.gif" width="1842" height="53" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="1" height="53" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="5" rowspan="10">
            <img src="images/Design_20.gif" width="986" height="504" alt=""></td>
        <td colspan="5" rowspan="2">
            <img src="images/Design_21.gif" width="324" height="29" alt=""></td>
        <td colspan="2" rowspan="6">
            <img src="images/Design_22.gif" width="16" height="230" alt=""></td>
        <td colspan="6">
            <img src="images/Design_23.gif" width="324" height="12" alt=""></td>
        <td colspan="3" rowspan="10">
            <img src="images/Design_24.gif" width="192" height="504" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="1" height="12" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="4">
            <img src="images/Design_25.gif" width="70" height="205" alt=""></td>
        <td colspan="3" rowspan="3">
            <img src="images/Design_26.gif" width="185" height="161" alt=""></td>
        <td colspan="2" rowspan="4">
            <img src="images/Design_27.gif" width="69" height="205" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="1" height="17" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" rowspan="3">
            <img src="images/Design_28.gif" width="105" height="188" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/Design_29.gif" width="115" height="114" alt=""></td>
        <td colspan="2" rowspan="3">
            <img src="images/Design_30.gif" width="104" height="188" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="1" height="114" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">
            <img src="images/Design_31.gif" width="115" height="74" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="1" height="30" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">
            <img src="images/Design_32.gif" width="185" height="44" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="1" height="44" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="5" rowspan="2">
            <img src="images/Design_33.gif" width="324" height="15" alt=""></td>
        <td colspan="6">
            <img src="images/Design_34.gif" width="324" height="13" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="1" height="13" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="4">
            <img src="images/Design_35.gif" width="13" height="274" alt=""></td>
        <td colspan="3" rowspan="2">
            <img src="images/Design_36.gif" width="97" height="146" alt=""></td>
        <td colspan="4">
            <img src="images/Design_37.gif" width="230" height="2" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="1" height="2" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="5" rowspan="2">
            <img src="images/Design_38.gif" width="324" height="217" alt=""></td>
        <td colspan="4" rowspan="2">
            <img src="images/Design_39.gif" width="230" height="217" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="1" height="144" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">
            <img src="images/Design_40.gif" width="3" height="128" alt=""></td>
        <td colspan="2">
            <img src="images/Design_41.gif" width="94" height="73" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="1" height="73" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="5">
            <img src="images/Design_42.gif" width="324" height="55" alt=""></td>
        <td colspan="6">
            <img src="images/Design_43.gif" width="324" height="55" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="1" height="55" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="21">
            <img src="images/Design_44.gif" width="1842" height="323" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="1" height="323" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="48" height="1" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="74" height="1" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="567" height="1" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="173" height="1" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="124" height="1" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="11" height="1" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="94" height="1" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="115" height="1" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="1" height="1" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="103" height="1" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="13" height="1" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="3" height="1" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="70" height="1" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="24" height="1" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="16" height="1" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="145" height="1" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="47" height="1" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="22" height="1" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="70" height="1" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="74" height="1" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="48" height="1" alt=""></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<!-- End Save for Web Slices -->
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the table width to 100% does not really center anything.
It sets the table to fill all *available* space (mind the space for scrollbars).
Since your table cells contain images with a defined width, these images define the (minimum) width for each table cell (and subsequently for each column)
So, if your screen is smaller than the sum total of your images, you will need to scroll horizontally to see the entire result.

In general, if you want to use a table to center your content, nested tables are the simplest way:

```
<table width="100%">
  <tr>
    <td align="center">
      <table><!-- this is the actual content table -->
        <tr>
          <td>this is my content</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Hope that helps a bit?

And a side note: Most people will tell you that creating a layout entirely from tables is quite old-fashionned. `<div>`s and CSS might be a better approach, but i gather you are a beginner?

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Yes I am a beginner, so I guess I'm going to be  trying this like you said.

Comment: Is it possible for you to insert your code into mine? That would REALLY be appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: @EdmBay  Just enter your table instead of the table with the comment after it and you are good to go. Or take the first and last three lines and prepend / append them to your code.

Comment: It creates a white spacing between the images, and it breaks them :(. At this point, I'd like you to insert it because I want this done asap.

Comment: While that is completely understandable, it is very much discouraged on this platform: SO is here to help you code, not to code for you. For that, there are freelance programmers ;-)